# Mongo index help for $or query

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am trying to understand how indexes can be applied to this MongoDB query:

```
{
    "account_id" : 1234,
    "supplier_id" : {
        "$gt" : 0
    },
    "$or" : [
        {
            "po_number" : {
                "$regex" : "blahblah",
                "$options" : "i"
            }
        },
        {
            "shipping.first_name" : {
                "$regex" : "blahblah",
                "$options" : "i"
            }
        },
        {
            "shipping.last_name" : {
                "$regex" : "blahblah",
                "$options" : "i"
            }
        },
        {
            "shipping.company" : {
                "$regex" : "blahblah",
                "$options" : "i"
            }
        },
        {
            "consumer_order_number" : "blahblah"
        },
        {
            "invoices.invoice_number" : "blahblah"
        },
        {
            "shipments.tracking_number" : "blahblah"
        }
    ],
    "test_flag" : {
        "$in" : [0,null]
    }
}
```

I understand that this is probably a slow query, but I want to see how anyone else would attack creating indexes for it. Could it possibly be a matter of reorganizing the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a bunch of testing, it turns out that the query needed to be rewritten to allow it to make full use of multiple indexes.  The rewritten version is:

```
{
"$or" : [
    {
        "po_number" : {"$regex" : "blahblah", "$options" : "i"}
        "account_id" : 1234,
        "supplier_id" : {"$gt" : 0},
        "test_flag" : {"$in" : [0,null]}
    },
    {
        "shipping.first_name" : {"$regex" : "blahblah", "$options" : "i"}
        "account_id" : 1234,
        "supplier_id" : {"$gt" : 0},
        "test_flag" : {"$in" : [0,null]}
    },
    {
        "shipping.last_name" : {"$regex" : "blahblah", "$options" : "i"}
        "account_id" : 1234,
        "supplier_id" : {"$gt" : 0},
        "test_flag" : {"$in" : [0,null]}
    },
    {
        "shipping.company" : {"$regex" : "blahblah", "$options" : "i"}
        "account_id" : 1234,
        "supplier_id" : {"$gt" : 0},
        "test_flag" : {"$in" : [0,null]}
    },
    {
        "consumer_order_number" : "blahblah"
        "account_id" : 1234,
        "supplier_id" : {"$gt" : 0},
        "test_flag" : {"$in" : [0,null]}
    },
    {
        "invoices.invoice_number" : "blahblah"
        "account_id" : 1234,
        "supplier_id" : {"$gt" : 0},
        "test_flag" : {"$in" : [0,null]}
    },
    {
        "shipments.tracking_number" : "blahblah"
        "account_id" : 1234,
        "supplier_id" : {"$gt" : 0},
        "test_flag" : {"$in" : [0,null]}
    }
],
```

}

Note how the only top-level element is the "$or".  If there are any other top-level elements, only a single index can be used.  I created the following indexes that the query ended up using:

```
db.Order.ensureIndex({po_number: 1, account_id: -1, supplier_id: -1});
db.Order.ensureIndex({"shipping.first_name": 1, account_id: -1, supplier_id: -1});
db.Order.ensureIndex({"shipping.last_name": 1, account_id: -1, supplier_id: -1});
db.Order.ensureIndex({"shipping.company": 1, account_id: -1, supplier_id: -1});
db.Order.ensureIndex({consumer_order_number: 1, account_id: -1, supplier_id: -1});
db.Order.ensureIndex({"invoices.invoice_number": 1, account_id: -1, supplier_id: -1});
db.Order.ensureIndex({"shipments.tracking_number": 1, account_id: -1, supplier_id: -1});
```

As a side-note, I also found a lot of speed by changing the $regex entry.

This version is the slowest, due to the case-insensitivity, and the term is allowed to be found in the middle of the string.

```
{"$regex" : "blahblah", "$options" : "i"}
```

If the case-insensitivity can be done without, and we can assume that the term can always be a "starts with..." value, then the following is extremely fast:

```
{"$regex" : "^blahblah"}
```

Note that there is no "*" on the end, since it is implied. See https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/regex/.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would begin with is creating a compound index on the main three fields of your query, because it's a low hanging fruit:

```
db.yourcollection.createIndex({account_id: 1, test_flag: 1, supplier_id: 1})
```

The 1s indicate range indices created in increasing key order. In particular, it supports the $gt query on the supplier_id.

The order can be played with, in particular the last two, but account_id should probably stay first: Your query is highly selective on it, so that it's good to have an index that keeps the same account_ids together.

The $or part of the query would then be performed in memory, which should be good enough if the above three fields are selective.